# How to prevent Carousel from rerendering

Tags: reactjs

I am using React Grid Carousel in my app and have an images grid and a function that if an image in that grid is clicked it opens up a modal.

Here is some important bits of the code:

Parent component:

```
 function parentComponent () {

    return (
           <section>
              <div>
            <h1>
                Images
            </h1>
        </div>
            <ChildComponent />
          </section>

    );
```

Child component:

```
   function childComponent () {

  const handleModal = useCallback(
        e => {
            setImageId(e.target.id);
            setModalOpen(true);        
    },
        [modalOpen, imageId]
    );

}
   const data = sectionData.map((data, i) => {
        return data;
    });
    const items = data[0].map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <div id={i} onClick={e => handleModal(e)}>
                <Image width={200} height={200} alt={item.name} />
            </div>
        );
    });
    return (
                <Carousel
                    cols={2}
                    rows={3}
                    showDots
                >
                    {items.map((item, i) => (
                        <Carousel.Item key={i}>
                            {item}
                        </Carousel.Item>
                    ))}
                </Carousel>
     {modalOpen && <MemberModal/>}
    );
```

The problem I am having is that if I am in let's say, page 2 of the modal, once I click in an image, the carousel goes back to the first page as the result of the rerender caused by the state change that happens on the `handleModal`.
I have tried React.memo this component and the parent too just in case and also using `useCallback` but nothing seems to work. I just simply cannot stop the rerender.

Any idea on how to accomplish stoping the rerender or sorting the issue at all?

Answer (score 1):

React re-renders children components automatically after a state change. If your state is inside `MyComponent` it will re-render everything inside the `return` function.

But if you wrap the `Carousel` part of your component in memo, it will compare its props and if the props have not changed, it wont re-render the component.

```
const Example = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Carousel
       cols={2}
       rows={3}
       showDots
      >
     {items.map((item, i) => (
      <Carousel.Item key={i}>
        {item}
      </Carousel.Item>
     ))}
     </Carousel>
    </>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Example);
```

Comment: this is what I mean, I have tried doing that and rerender still occurring. I am adding Example in React.memo in a parent component. still happening

Comment: That's strange, it should not re-render. Can you update your question with more code, for example the location of your state, any other parent component which might re-render.